# How to colonize a planet?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire

I took the first 3 tutorials and played a game. It went fine until I tried to colonize a planet. A neutral and perfect planet. But I couldn't colonize it there was no button for that. It was possible in the tutorial. But I can't do it in this game. Do I have to research the ability?

The [wikia wiki](http://sinsofasolarempire.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) it just said some of the capital ships could colonize.
I have a capital ship but the button isn't there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a colony freight, or a colony capital ship to colonize new planets. Each of the three races have one - the frigates are Protev Colony Frigate for the TEC, Missionary Vessel for the Advent and Jarun Migrator for the Vasari. They should be in the last position in your shipyard's ship construction menu.

The capital ships for each of the races are the Akkan Battlecruiser for the TEC, Progenitor Mothership for the Advent and Jarrasul Evacuator for the Vasari.

Once you have one of these ships in orbit around a neutral planet, click on the [image] **Colonize** button, and the ship will automatically move into position and colonize the planet. During the process you'll see shuttles launching from the ship to send colonists down onto the planet.